# Emit two values when a value is emitted

Tags: rxjs

Is it possible to emit two values in exchange for an emitted value?

Let's say I have this code

```
of(1,2,3).pipe( <what goes here?> )
```

and I want the resulting marble diagram to be

```
---1---1.5---2---2.5---3---3.5---->
```

That is for each of the values emitted by the `of`, two values will be generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `mergeMap` (or `concatMap`):

```
of(1,2,3)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(v => [v, 2 + 0.5]),
  )
```

`mergeMap` will iterate the array returned from the projection function and reemit each value.

Answer (score 1):

here it is with concatMap:

```
const mappingFn = n => Rx.Observable.of(n, n + 0.5);

o1.concatMap(mappingFn)
  .subscribe(c => console.log(c));
```

the mappingFn maps every value to two values